# Is there a metric that behaves in the following way?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Background:**

Given a metric space $(M, d)$, I am playing around to see if I can construct another metric on $M$ that somehow takes into account proximity to a subset $Y \subseteq M$. Call this new metric $d_Y$.

See the picture below:

[image]

The idea is that:

- $a_1$ and $a_2$ should be considered close together in $d_Y$, because they are close together in $d$
- $b_1$ and $b_2$ should be considered far apart in $d_Y$, because they are far apart in $d$
- $c_1$ and $c_2$ should be considered far apart in $d_Y$, because they are far apart in $d$ and only one of them is close to $Y$
- $d_1$ and $d_2$ should be considered close together in $d_Y$, because they are both close to $Y$ in $d$
- $e_1$ and $e_2$ should be considered close together in $d_Y$, maybe even $d_Y(e_1, e_2) = 0$, because both $e_1$ and $e_2$ are in $Y$.

**Question:**

Can this be accomplished, and if so, how?

I was looking at the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), which compares the distance between subsets $X, Y \subseteq M$, and wondering if this could induce a metric on $M$ if I keep $Y$ fixed and restrict $X$ to only be subsets of $M$ of cardinality two. But I'm not sure if this makes a metric $d_Y$, or whether it's the most sensible way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

All elements of $Y$ should have the same magnitude, otherwise the distance between them could not be less than the difference between their magnitudes.

Some examples:

- On the complex plane we define distance as $d(z_1,z_2)=||z_1|-|z_2||$ then all points with the same magnitude are at zero distance from each other, for instance, the set $|z|=1$ will work as $Y$.
- In spaces with zero divisors, the sets of zero divisors satisfy as they have magnitude $0$. For instance, in split-complex numbers the two diagonals $\Re(z)=\Im(z)$ and $\Re(z)=-\Im(z)$ would serve as $Y$ in this case.
- In dual numbers, any line $\Re(z)=a$ also can serve as $Y$.

Comment: $||z_1|-|z_2||$ is not a metric.

Comment: @geetha290krm well, the conditions set in th OP cannot be met if positivity property of metric (${\displaystyle {\text{if }}x\neq y{\text{, then }}d(x,y)>0}$) is satisfied if $Y$ has more than one element. So, in any case, our "distance" is not a metric.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a fairly natural way to define a (pseudo) metric $d_Y$ on $M$ which has the properties you desire.

Let $d_Y(a,b)=\min(d(a,b),\inf_{x,y \in Y}(d(a,x)+d(y,b)))$

This is indeed a (pseudo) metric (the only hard thing to check is the triangle inequality), it also makes all elements of $Y$ have distance zero to one another and all the other properties you wanted. The intuition for this is that we essentially let paths "jump" between points in $Y$.

This construction is very closely related to the concept of the quotient space of a metric space (essentially the main difference is that you don't treat all of the points of $Y$ as being equivalent) which you can read more about here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Quotient_metric_spaces

We can also use a slightly modified version of this construction to get a metric $\widehat{d_{\epsilon,Y}}$ for any $0<\epsilon \leq 1$.

Let $\widehat{d_{\epsilon,Y}}(a,b)=\min(d(a,b),\inf_{x,y \in Y}(d(a,x)+\epsilon d(x,y)+d(y,b)))$

Again it is easy to check this is a pseudometric and we also have $\epsilon d(a,b)\leq\widehat{d_{\epsilon,Y}}(a,b)$ and so it is a metric.

The intuition for this definition is rather than letting paths "jump" between points in $Y$ they can instead "move quickly" between points in $Y$.

If we additionally have $Y$ bounded and not a singleton then we can choose any $\epsilon_0$ with $0<\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sup_{x,y\in Y}d(x,y)} \leq 1$. We then define $\widetilde{d_{\epsilon_0,Y}}(a,b)=d_{\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sup_{x,y\in Y}d(x,y)},Y}(a,b)$

We now have $d_Y(a,b) \leq \widetilde{d_{\epsilon_0,Y}}(a,b)\leq d_Y(a,b)+\epsilon_0$ and so we can choose $\epsilon_0$ to approximate $d_Y$ arbitrarily well.

Comment: This might be exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. I need to study this, so I will not accept yet, but my intuition is that if you make equivalence classes out of $M$ such that $Y$ is one equivalence class, and everything else is just singletons, then the pseudometric becomes a metric? Would that be right? Thanks again.

Comment: @Novice It is almost the case that you would get a metric if you do that. Specifically if $Y$ is "nice enough" (I think being closed should work) then you get a metric. As a counterexample for the general statement consider the case where the original metric space is $\Bbb{R}$ (with the usual metric) and $Y=(-\inf,0)$ then $d_Y((-\inf,0),\{0\})=0$ but $(-\inf,0)\not\equiv\{0\}$.